# Android Studio a strange error in layout xml

Tags: xml, layout

in my layout.xml have a strange error i don't know how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: You probably have some problem somewhere else in the document that is causing the parser to behave strangely.

Comment: I try to delete other codes in the document, but the problem also exist